# Update Configurable Product Base Price

Tags: magento2, database, configurable-product

Is it possible to update the ***Configurable Product Base price*** once it has been set as ***the field is uneditable once*** it has been saved. Ie either Via Import or direct on the database.

Comment: did not get ur point `the field is uneditable once`?

Comment: He probably means it is disabled

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2 Configurable product don't have the base price. To repeat m1 behavior you need update price for all child product.

Answer (score 0):

I think this was more a case of the update to 2.1.5 however, I just exported the product list and tidied up the prices and a few other anomalies and re-imported and this seems to have worked. All the products are correct and back in stock now.